# Who is the customer who has both an account and a loan in the same branch?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables: 
[image: http://imgur.com/ylyXYZP]

I want to know: Who is the customer who has both an account and a loan in the same branch?

I have tried 2 pieces of code like the following:

```
select distinct depositor.customer_name, account.branch_name
from (borrower inner join loan on borrower.loan_number=loan.loan_number) 
inner join 
( depositor inner join account on depositor.account_number=account.account_number ) 
on (account.branch_name=loan.branch_name and borrower.customer_name=depostior.customer_name);
```

and this:

```
select account.branch_name, depositor.customer branch_name
from account, depostior
where depositor.customer_name, account.branch_name
in ( borrower inner join loan on borrower.loan_number=loan.loan_number );
```

In this latest one, I have tried somehow with nested query but had no success.

So how can i solve this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct d.customer_name, a.branch_name
from depositor d,  account a, borrower b, loan l
where 
d.account_number = a.account_number
and d.customer_name = b.customer_name
and b.loan_number = l.loan_number
and l.branch_name = a.branch_name
```

Rewritten in INNER JOIN syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.customer_name, a.branch_name
FROM depositor d
INNER JOIN account a ON d.account_number = a.account_number
INNER JOIN borrower b ON d.customer_name = b.customer_name
INNER JOIN loan l ON b.loan_number = l.loan_number
       AND l.branch_name = a.branch_name
```

Comment: We tend to discourage comma joins around here

Comment: Posted another answer using the Inner Join syntax. Better?

Comment: No need to post multiple answer, just extend your answer by editing

Answer (score -1):

Rewritten in INNER JOIN syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        d.customer_name, a.branch_name
    FROM
        depositor d
            INNER JOIN
        account a ON d.account_number = a.account_number
            INNER JOIN
        borrower b ON d.customer_name = b.customer_name
            INNER JOIN
        loan l ON b.loan_number = l.loan_number
            AND l.branch_name = a.branch_name
```